# Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation Module Breaks My Site Layout

Tags: performance, css-js-aggregation

When I enable my module Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation it breaks my site layout.  Is there something I need to do before or after when enabling this module.

To fix the site layout I need to disable the Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation module and it works again.

Comment: Check your status page and log messages. Probably a permissions issue.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, here is some steps to check:

1. check if your css loaded and optimised in your page source code some files like `/sites/default/files/css/css_QnKw33sohmgUyVqs9lGXvHTJTZsphXTkXdkVVmt25ts.css` if it's no check if there is any errors in your console, if this is the case **Check your status page and log messages, and permissions**
2. If it's yes all files well loaded **this is was my case** i had some css errors that's why even my css files loaded not taking any effect:
   So i had to check / validate all my css files and correct any errors.
   I used this https://codebeautify.org/cssvalidate.
   there is a lot other websites to validate your css.
   I hope this help you !